# Converting Python data structures to JavaScript, including functions

Tags: python, json, django, c3.js

I'm creating charts for my Django app using C3.js. In my Django template, I have a JavaScript snippet like this:

```
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({{ chart_data|safe }});
</script>
```

In the view, I set up the chart using a Python data structure, which is converted to JSON before being rendered by the template:

```
chart = {
    'bindto': '#chart',
    'data': {
        'columns': [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    }
}
return render_to_response('chart.html', {'chart_data': json.dumps(chart)})
```

That works fine, and I get something like [this example](http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html#generate).

For more complicated C3 charts, I need to be able to include JavaScript functions in the argument to c3.generate. (For example the `onclick` value in [this donut chart](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html).) But JSON doesn't support representing functions, and adding `'onclick': 'function (d, i) { ... };'` to the Python dict just results in a string when JSON encoded. Trying to subclass `json.JSONEncoder` seems fruitless, as what I need to output isn't valid JSON, it's actual JavaScript.

Is there a neat way of doing this? At the moment I'm doing a kludgy workaround, inserting the JavaScript function code into the result of `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 2):

On reflection, I think what I'm asking is a case of approaching the problem the wrong way, or [using the wrong tools to solve the problem](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).

The data structure given to `c3.generate()` contains two things:

1. configuration for how the data is structured and how the chart should look, and
2. the actual data to be rendered in the chart.

There's no particular reason I need to have the configuration setup in the Django view code. With that realization, I can move the configuration (including the problematic "onclick" JavaScript function I wanted to add) to the template, and inject the data into a separate variable.

The template would be:

```
<script>
var columns = {{ chart_columns|safe }};
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: columns,
      onclick: function (d, i) { /* ... */ }
    }
});
</script>
```

And the view code:

```
chart = [
    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
]
return render_to_response('chart.html', {'chart_columns': json.dumps(chart)})
```

As well as solving my problem, this fits better with Django's Model-View-Template design.